# Unable to start Django Gamification Server - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, linux, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have been tasked to get Gamification up and running in our department to motivate the staff.

I found this https://github.com/ngageoint/gamification-server which is an opensource gamification server released by the NGA.

I have followed all the instructions to the letter but cant get the server up.

Some Info:
Platform - Ubuntu 14 LTS
Packages Installed Before Getting Started on Gamification:
PostgreSQL
Python Python-dev
Git
Virtualenv

I am able to install the dependencies but when i go to the second task "paver createdb" I get the following error:

```
---> pavement.createdb


Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavement.createdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paver/tasks.p                                                                                        y", line 195, in _run_task
    return do_task()
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paver/tasks.p                                                                                        y", line 192, in do_task
    return func(**kw)
  File "pavement.py", line 87, in createdb
    from gamification import settings
  File "/etc/gamification-server/gamification/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from gamification.core.models import Points
  File "/etc/gamification-server/gamification/core/models.py", line 27, in <modu                                                                                        le>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contri                                                                                        b/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middle                                                                                        ware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/                                                                                        cache.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import caches
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/c                                                                                        ache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/_                                                                                        _init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/pyenv/gamification/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/_                                                                                        _init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured.                                                                                         You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call                                                                                         settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have configured the settings.py file as per instruction and installed all packages and dependencies as required but getting absolutely nowhere.

Settings.py

```
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = [
    # ("Your Name", "your_email@example.com"),
]

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": "gamification",
        "USER": "game_manager",
        "PASSWORD": "django-gamification",
        "HOST": "localhost",
        "PORT": "5432"
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "media")

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
# MEDIA_URL = "/site_media/media/"

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don"t put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps" "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
#STATIC_ROOT = '{0}'.format('/var/www/static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "gamification/site_media")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# Additional locations of static files
#STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),
#]

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = "z7lz3v!zl9yohg2(yfk0!cmv)#lkl6znja*hh877b&byujuu7875vfr"

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
]

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "account.context_processors.account",
    "pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
]


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "gamification.urls"

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = "gamification.wsgi.application"

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # hyperlinked styles by default
    # only used if the 'serializer_class' attribute is not set on view
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS': 'rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer',

    # Use Django's standard 'django.contrib.auth' permissions, or read-only for unauthorized users
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly']
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",

    # theme
    "pinax_theme_bootstrap",
    "django_forms_bootstrap",

    # external
    "account",
    "metron",
    "eventlog",
    "bootstrap3",
    "south",
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "mptt",

    # project
    "gamification",
    "gamification.badges",
    "gamification.core",
    "gamification.events",
]

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": True,
        },
    }
}

FIXTURE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "fixtures"),
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP = True
ACCOUNT_USE_OPENID = False
ACCOUNT_REQUIRED_EMAIL = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION = False
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 2

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "account.auth_backends.UsernameAuthenticationBackend",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( '192.168.5.131:8000', 'localhost:8000', )
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ( 'GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS' )

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
```

UPDATE -- For anyone that finds this code and struggles with the same thing.
In the pavement.py file under the task createdb and create_db_user i added the following 2 lines

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]="gamification.settings"
```

--UPDATE--

Finally got the thing to work. Seems there are a couple steps missing in the setup of the gamification server.

Before issuing `Paver createdb` I ran `paver install_fixture` and `paver sync_initial` this sorted it out for me and the server is now running perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i manage to resolve this matter myself. If anyone finds this code and wants to use it as a gamification server follow the below steps:

1. Setup your OS (I used Linux Ubuntu)
2. Install python, postgresql, git, pip, libpq-dev
3. Create and Activate virtual env
4. Clone the code to your cwd
5. Install Paver
6. Install Dependencies
7. run command paver sync_initial, paver install_fixture
8. Paver createdb
9. Paver create_db_user
10. python manage.py createsuperuser
11. python manage.py runserver

That should get things up and going. See my original post for the changes i made to some of the files which would also help in setting up the server correctly.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with the commands above, I was still having trouble creating the database, user and tables with the createdb and create_db_user commands.  So, I started thinking that maybe it was a permissions issue.

The following helped me get the database populated (note that this may be obvious to most, but just wasn't for me).

These steps are for Ubuntu, but I think they will work on other Linux types as long as Postgres 8.x or greater, Python2.7 and the VirtualEnv are installed and working.

Login into Postgres:

```
$ bash #=> run under bash if not already
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="gamification.settings"
$ source ~/pyenv/gamification/bin/activate
$ sudo service postgresql start
$ psql -U postgres
postgres-# CREATE USER game_manager WITH PASSWORD 'supersecret';
postgres-# CREATE DATABASE gamification;
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE gamification to game_manager;
postgres-# ALTER USER GRANT SELECT ON gamification to game_manager;
postgres-# ALTER USER GRANT INSERT ON gamification to game_manager;
postgres-# ALTER USER GRANT DELETE ON gamification to game_manager;
postgres-# ALTER USER GRANT RULE ON gamification to game_manager;
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON table-name to public; #=> this step may be unnecessary
$ python manage.py syncdb
$ python manage.py syncdb #=> run it again
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.core
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.badges
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.event
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.core #=> run it again
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.badges #=> run it again
$ python manage.py migrate gamification.events #=> run it again
```

Disregard errors.  They are (I think) because of the circular dependencies mentioned in the post above.

Comment: what i also found is you can run the commands sync_initial and install fixture which will create the database and tables for you. if you look in the pavement file you will see a bunch of extra commands which is not listed in the original how-to. I am busy working on a more detailed how-to for this which i will share.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Looking closely at the stacktrace there seems to be circular-reference to import the settings.

The createdb task imports settings >> the gamification (the init py file) imports core.models >> which imports the django User >> causes the settings to be imported to look for DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS ...

I think you better look at whether this is a stable build of the Gamification Server package.

**Original answer:**

The full error is:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not
>   configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.

Django (1.8) has the [CACHES setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES) pre-set with the required 'default' backend. So for vanilla Django it works straight up with no CACHES setting declared.

To me the error implies the Django settings object isn't initialised. It's possible that the settings.py hasn't been loaded (possible if paver createdb isn't a Django management command).

Occasionally I've found this type of error when my settings.py has a syntax error and isn't being parsed properly by the interpreter. You can try using the python shell and running "import settings.py" to check it directly.

Comment: i have updated my original post to show the content of my settings file

Comment: The settings.py exists at the expected path? You might go trial-and-error by 1) renaming the settings file to check it's being read at the right path, 2) stripping back any changes/customisations you made to the settings file until it works.

Comment: i have looked at the pavement file now which paver uses to execute the tasks, the createdb task imports the settings from the gamification folder and then sets out to try and create a database in postgres

Comment: could the python interpreter be the problem here? i have loaded code in Pycharm and see errors "Python 2.7 does not have module builtins"

Comment: builtins are in the 'future' package to provide cross compatibility with python 3. Although I wouldn't necessarily trust PyCharm if you're still getting things set up. It looks like an unrelated issue.

Comment: Thanks, i have a dev machine running ubuntu where i am trying to get the thing working and another where i am checking the code with. tried your suggestion of renaming or moving the settings file and also tried starting off fresh but to no avail

Comment: I have all but given up by now, configured every single django file that calls the cache but still nothing. same error

Comment: got the thing up and running. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. Curious what the root-cause was. Perhaps my answer got you over the line, or you can answer your own question and award it so the next person who experiences this can benefit.

Comment: what i personally think is the instructions set out by the developer was a bit vague. also i had to define the django settings in each of my paver tasks. i updated my original posts with all the details.